# Thread called by button does not exit after function is done

Tags: python, tkinter, python-multithreading

**Python Verison 3.7 | NPM version 6.2.0 | Google Lighthouse Package version 4.0.0**

I am trying to create a rather simple Tkinter window to automate the Google lighthouse NPM package, but am failing while trying to stop a thread.

**The thread:**

```
lighthouse_thread = threading.Thread(target=start_lighthouse)
```

**And the Button to start the thread:**

```
Start_Ligthouse = Button(root, text="Starten", command=lighthouse_thread.start)
Start_Ligthouse.place(x=850, y=312)
Start_Ligthouse.config(state=DISABLED)
root.after(100, CheckInOut)
```

**The function looks like this:**

```
def start_lighthouse():                                                                                                                                         
    global filenumber
    global reportlocation
    global instantkill
    global file

    Start_Ligthouse.config(state=DISABLED)   
    for url in file:
        url = url.rstrip("\n")
        print(url)
        filename = url.replace("https","").replace("/","-").replace("\n","").replace(":","").replace("--","")

        if os.path.isfile(reportlocation + "/" + filename + ".html"):
            print("EXISTS!")
            filenumber = 2
            while True:                                                                                                                                         
                newfilename = filename + "{}".format(filenumber)
                if not os.path.isfile(reportlocation + "/" + newfilename + ".html"):
                    filename = newfilename
                    break
                filenumber += 1
        if instantkill:
            break


        #os.system("lighthouse --disable-device-emulation --throttling-method=provided --preset=perf --quiet --output-path={}/{}.html {}".format(reportlocation,filename,url))

    CheckIn = False
    CheckOut = False
    print("LoopEnded")
```

I commented the os.system command so I can run through the list quickly. If I were to call the function again, I get the error that the thread cant be started twice (which I understand.) But as far as I understood, the thread should terminate after the function was done.

My question is: How can I get the Thread to terminate after it has finished what it is supposed to do?

[Full code can be found here](https://github.com/HexaVFX/Google-Lighthouse-Helper/blob/master/TkinterFensterWIP.pyw)

Comment: the thread has probably exited, but in order to run it a second time you need to recreate it, you can't just call start a second time

Comment: also you are having a threading issue but completely omitted any code that show how you set up and start your thread, that should be part of the question not via a link

Comment: @JamesKent I'll update the question with the code for the thread

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @JamesKent i fixed it.

Instead of calling the thread with the button i created a function that creates a thread.

```
def create_thread():
    print("Thread Created")
    lighthouse_thread = threading.Thread(target=start_lighthouse)
    lighthouse_thread.start()
```

The button now calls this function and thus creates a new thread.

```
Start_Ligthouse = Button(root, text="Starten", command=create_thread)
```